# Unable to download whole html page - Objective C/Xcode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

I am using the following lines of code to download and save an html page ::

```
NSURL *goo = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://www.google.com"];
NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:goo]; 
NSString *html = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; //Remove the autorelease if using ARC

NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"];
NSLog(@"%@", documentsDirectory);
NSString *htmlFilePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"file.html"];
[html writeToFile:htmlFilePath atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
```

After downloading and saving it, I need to re-use it i.e. upload it. But, I am unable to download the css and image files alongwith the html page i.e. while re-uploading it .. I am not getting the images that should have been displayed on the google home page ..

Can someone help me sort out the issue ?? Thanks and Regards.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Download a file using cocoa](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2575553/download-a-file-using-cocoa)

Answer (score 0):

The data that is being downloaded is just what the web server returns - pure html. If you need the resources from inside - images/sounds/flash/css/javascripts/etc.. you have parse this html and download all other resources.. Your html may also contain the full path of those resources so you may need to change their urls to be relative (if you want to display it offline or upload it to another server). Parsing can be done with regular expressions or some other 3rd party parsers or libraries that can download the whole web page...
You may take a look at [ASIWebPageRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/ASIWebPageRequest), which claims to be able to download a whole website, but I haven't tried this functionality...

Comment: I haven't tried it too .. I am myself pretty new to objective C.

Comment: Take a look at the docs of `ASIWebPageRequest`, there are samples how to use it, as well as some limitations it has...

Comment: is there any other option apart from ASIWebPAgeRequest ??

Comment: I don't recommend you parsing by your own as it's a hard work and requires a decent amount of knowledge. There are probably other libraries that could do it. Have a search, something useful might come out...

Answer (score 0):

Use of [ASIWebPageRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/ASIWebPageRequest) will solve problem :

```
  - (void)downloadHtml:(NSURL *)url
 {
   // Assume request is a property of our controller
   // First, we'll cancel any in-progress page load
   [[self request] setDelegate:nil];
   [[self request] cancel];

   [self setRequest:[ASIWebPageRequest requestWithURL:url]];
   [[self request] setDelegate:self];
   [[self request] setDidFailSelector:@selector(webPageFetchFailed:)];
   [[self request] setDidFinishSelector:@selector(webPageFetchSucceeded:)];

   // Tell the request to embed external resources directly in the page
   [[self request] setUrlReplacementMode:ASIReplaceExternalResourcesWithData];

   // It is strongly recommended you use a download cache with ASIWebPageRequest
   // When using a cache, external resources are automatically stored in the cache
   // and can be pulled from the cache on subsequent page loads
   [[self request] setDownloadCache:[ASIDownloadCache sharedCache]];

   // Ask the download cache for a place to store the cached data
   // This is the most efficient way for an ASIWebPageRequest to store a web page
   NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,     NSUserDomainMask, YES);
   NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
   [[self request] setDownloadDestinationPath:documentsDirectory] // downloaded path
   //[[ASIDownloadCache sharedCache] pathToStoreCachedResponseDataForRequest:[self request]]]; use this instead of documentsDirectory if u want to cache the page

   [[self request] startAsynchronous];
}

//These are delegates methods:
- (void)webPageFetchFailed:(ASIHTTPRequest *)theRequest
{
  // Obviously you should handle the error properly...
  NSLog(@"%@",[theRequest error]);
}

- (void)webPageFetchSucceeded:(ASIHTTPRequest *)theRequest
{
   NSString *response = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:
   [theRequest downloadDestinationPath] encoding:[theRequest responseEncoding] error:nil];
   // Note we're setting the baseURL to the url of the page we downloaded. This is important!
  [webView loadHTMLString:response baseURL:[request url]];
}
```

Comment: I am using a button called as "download html" .. how should I use its IBAction ?? I mean here u you are suggesting another IBAction ??

Comment: Also, how and where should I declare this "request" property ??

Comment: in button called as "download html" call my [self downloadHtml:[NSURL urlWithString@"url address"]]; and add this delegates in .m file

Comment: where should I declare this "request" ?? what is it ??

Comment: integrate [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) into your code and then copy all methods into your code now on your button method for download add this [self downloadHtml:[NSURL urlWithString@"url address"]];

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
/// js=yourHtmlSring;
 NSString *js;  (.h)
 [self.myWebView loadHTMLString:js baseURL:nil];
 }
```

//delegate

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
[myWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:js];
 }`
```

Comment: whare and how should I declare this dic ??

Comment: the images are still not getting displayed .. I tried out ur code :-/

Answer (score 0):

Hey I don't think you can  download all the files from google just try with any other url . And you can directly write the `NSData` to your file `htmlFilePath`.

```
[data writeToFile:htmlFilePath atomically:YES];
```